# Android sideloading from my site

Tags: android, sideloading

I want to make my app be downloadable from my site, then I read about sideloading. Which, as to what I read, will install the app to the users phone instead of downloading the apk. Is there a way that I can make my site sideload my app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to do this. Sideloading (as in installing the app for the user) only works if the user has adb installed which usually only true for developers and root users. It is much better to provide either a download of the apk or to provide a link to the play store.

Comment: Isn't it that unrooted phones just need their 'unknown sources' option set to checked to be able to sideload?

Comment: Sideloading refers to transferring the .apk to the device (by downloading, USB, etc.) and installing it locally. So yes, you just need to go to Settings > Security and check Unknown sources to sideload an apk.

Comment: He also said that it would install the app instead of just downloading it. From what my experience you need to have adb installed to do this. And most users that don't have root don't have adb installed (I know I'm still wrong, I edited it...)